# onselect remove element from Bootstrap Multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I have two bootstrap mutiselect dropdown. And my requirement is, If I select any one option from first dropdown then selected option should be removed from second dropdown.
Also if I deselect it then it should be add to second dropdown.

Here is link

[https://jsfiddle.net/cpxavier/6escna8k](https://jsfiddle.net/cpxavier/6escna8k/)

Comment: jsfiddle link:   https://jsfiddle.net/cpxavier/6escna8k/

Comment: jsfiddle.net/cpxavier/6escna8k

Comment: Please [edit] the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your *document.ready* to this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.multi2').multiselect({ // this is the second multiselect
        includeSelectAllOption: false,
        nonSelectedText: 'Select Teams',
    });
    $('.multi1').multiselect({ // this is the first multiselect
        includeSelectAllOption: false,
        nonSelectedText: 'Select Teams',
        onChange: function(option, checked, select) { // implement onChange listener
        // clear all selection of the second dropdown - This will be called whenever there's a change in the first multiselect
        // You can think of puting in some additional conditions here.
            $('.multi2').multiselect('clearSelection', false);
        }
    });
});
```

You'll also need to update your html as -

```
<select id="team0" name="team0[]" class="multi1" multiple="multiple"><!-- first dropdown-->
```

and

```
<select id="team1" name="team0[]" class="multi2" multiple="multiple"><!-- second dropdown-->
```

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/yellen/fw32gwd2/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

For more references: http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you want to achieve the multiple selection.

But this jQuery Library is very good for multiple selection, easy to manipulate and more flexible.

[JQuery Magic Suggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/)

With good documentations

Comment: Ya...that is not what i want.Please check jsfiddle..here is the link.https://jsfiddle.net/cpxavier/6escna8k/